# ruby on rails can't create physical relationships with models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, model

I'm not sure why I don't have the physical foreign key for my 1 to many relationship.Order HAS MANY Comments. Same with other relationships.

Models:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :invoices
    has_many :payments through => :invoices
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_many :options
    has_many :media through => :options
    has_many :auctions
    has_many :factmails
    belongs_to :orderstatus

end


class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :order

end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :content
      t.belongs_to :order, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.comments (
    id int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('comments_id_seq'::regclass),
    content text NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS=FALSE
) ;
```

What am I doing wrong? what's the correct strategy when you first define models and then want to create relationships between them?

Comment: That should be either `:through => ...` (old-style) or `through: ...` (current style).

Comment: It seems odd you're not getting an `order_id` column with that migration.

Comment: that's why I'm asking.. it doesn't appear afterwards

Comment: Is it possible that the name `:order` is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have not modified the migration file to add the line

`t.belongs_to :order, index: true`

after running the command `rails db: migrate`
 If so, you need to rollback the migrations and re-execute them

Comment: `:order` is a symbol. `order` is an undefined variable.